# When to add salts to RO brewing water

Tags: mash-ph, gypsum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I put minerals back into distilled or reverse osmosis water?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/4924/how-can-i-put-minerals-back-into-distilled-or-reverse-osmosis-water)

This weekend I'll be brewing a recipe from Mitch Steele's 'IPA' book. The recipe has a very exact water profile, so I decided to use RO water and build the water with salts.

The question is, when do I add these salts? I can add them to the mash water. I can add them to the sparge water. I can add them to the boil kettle. I can add them to all three. What's the best approach?

Comment: The linked 'duplicate' question doesn't really cover the same information that I'm looking for here. In that question the top answers get into what minerals to add & why, but I'm asking When to add these minerals.

Comment: I agree, Hopwise. Something I just learned is that gypsum does not acidify plain water, even though it lowers mash pH in the presence of the malt. Even, so this might be more of a wiki-style question since its a bit open-ended.

Comment: I feel like "How do I add them" is sufficiently similar to "When do I add them" to make the questions pretty much the same.   I don't think that aspect was answered adequately, but I'm not sure that it warrants another extremely similar question.